# SQL build junction table from tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MSSQL, and I have generated a table of tags such as this:

```
tag_id |  name
0      |  compost
1      |  ritual
...   ...
```

I have another table like this

```
obj_id |  name   |  desc
0      |  obj1   |  used for ritual
1      |  obj2   |  used for compost
2      |  obj3   |  compost and ritual
3      |  obj4   |  compost, ritual, compost
   ...
```

I am trying to write a query or procedure to populate a junction table where tags are LIKE a desc, without duplicates (yet allowing multiple tags for one item). For example, it should output:

```
tag_id | obj_id
0      | 1
0      | 2
0      | 3
1      | 0
1      | 2
1      | 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the query you want:

```
select t.tag_id, o.obj_id from tags t
inner join othertable o
on o.[desc] like '%' + t.name + '%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26c52/1)

---

BTW, better don't use `desc` for a column name. This forces you to put the name in square brackets all the time `[desc]` as you're using a keyword for the column name.